# How to pass variable from an HTML file to a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html

I have two different files: a .html and a .js.
In the html file I have a button, that when I click it I call a function located inside the .js file. In this moment, when I click the button, I want to pass a parameter that I receive from an  on the html file to the js one.
I've tried, from the js, to do Document.getElementById("idDelInput") but since the input is not inside the same file, it doesn't recognise the Document.

```js
function login() {
  //check the variable email
}
```

```html
<input id="email" type="text">
<button onClick="login()">Login</button>
```

Comment: `Document.getElementById("idDelInput")` should be `document.getElementById("email")`

Comment: Try document.getElementById("email")

Comment: You neither recieve input from files, nor you pass anything to a file. That is not even close to the concept as of how it works. The concept is  `document`, `DOM`, `script` and variable scope.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab the element first into your Javascript and then get the value from it. `document.getElementById("email")`, or `document.querySelector("#email")` will get your element into the javascript file. Then use `value` property to get its value.

```js
function login() {
  document.querySelector("#email").value;
}
```

```html
<input id="email" type="text">
<button onClick="login()">Login</button>
```